# Mysql results within a specific year on a datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to get results back within year 'N' on a datetime column... I was hoping I could do something like this: 
DOD BETWEEN '2014-1-1' AND '2013-1-1'
but I get nothing back with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`YEAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

```
WHERE YEAR(DOD) = 2013
```

Answer (score 2):

So indexes can be used:

```sql
WHERE dod >= '2013-01-01'
  AND dod < '2014-01-01'
```

or:

```sql
WHERE dod >= MAKEDATE(2013, 1)   -- first day of the year
  AND dod < MAKEDATE(2014, 1)
```